# PHPWord 0.11.0 font style underline

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpword, phpoffice

I have a problem with PHPWord that I belive is version 0.11.0, I use the PHPWord for CI.

The issues is I cannot find the right php script to make the underline, this is the latest script I got,

```
$section->addText(
    $text, 
    [ 'underline' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\AbstractStyle::UNDERLINE_SINGLE ], // Problem with this line
    [ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Alignment::ALIGN_CENTER ] // This one fine
);
```

But whenever the script I got, it always display an error or didnt give me what I want, (the underlined text).

This the error I got

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Undefined class constant 'UNDERLINE_SINGLE'
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\application\controllers\Print.php
>
> Line Number: 47
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

To implement a single underline, add an element:
`array('underline' => 'single')` in your styling array